# Error in theme(legend.position = "top") : could not find function "theme"

Tags: r, install.packages

After installing ggplot2, I had the problem that I couldn't install other packages or packages I actually already had.

The warning message was:

```
Error: Loading package or namespace for 'broom' in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]): failed
  Namespace ‘rlang’ 1.0.6 is already loaded, but >= 1.1.0 is required
In addition: Warning message:
Package ‘broom’ was created under R version 4.2.3
```

How can I fix this?

I already tried to update all packages.

Comment: What version of R are you using?

Comment: (1) The original has nothing to do with ggplot2, your title is a red herring. (2) The `rlang` error is what needs to be focused on. Restart R completely (all running instances of R), then reinstall `rlang`, then reinstall the package(s) you were attempting to install in the first place.

Comment: Now it works, thank you!